# Use of @Provider and @Component in CXF

Tags: cxf, provider

Can anyone explain about `@Provider` and `@Component` and when we need to use in `Apache CXF` for both `Rest` and `Soap` Implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two `@Provider` annotations, a JAX-RS standard annotation and a native CXF provider annotation. You can use them to mark a provider, it will be auto-discovered depending on the setup you use. `@Component` is a Spring annotation and can be used as an alternative.

If you are using a Spring Boot based setup see http://cxf.apache.org/docs/springboot.html for the different scanning options.